# Why are "had gone" and "had come" used instead of "went" and "came"?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-simple

This sentence has been nagging me since this morning.

> She had gone home as she had probably come. [Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rw9kDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4008&dq=%22She%20had%20gone%20home%20as%20she%20had%20probably%20come%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwissNHFvpTmAhWitXEKHUwEC9QQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22She%20had%20gone%20home%20as%20she%20had%20probably%20come%22&f=false)

Why are *had gone* and *had come* used instead of *went* and *came*?

Comment: Use of perfect constructions is dependent on **context**. Can you give us some more?

Comment: What @StoneyB said. Specifically for your example, it depends whether the contextual "narrative time" ***includes*** her going home (maybe the next sentence is going to tell us how she felt *while* going home). Or whether that was something she did ***earlier*** (maybe the narrative continues by saying something about how she felt ***after she got home***).

Comment: @fumblefingers   ok it was in one of the books!     .The groping she had done had been in this direction,she was searching for this hat and coat (a man's hat,a derby, as I had been careful to assure myself at the first handling)and, in them, she had gone home as she had probably come , and there was no man in the case , or if there were –

Answer (score 1):

The narrator is speaking about a past reference time when was alone in the house **after** the woman left. He realized *at that reference time* that the woman he **had seen** leave **had not gone** out into the winter night without adequate clothes but **had taken** a man's hat and **had gone home** in the same condition in which, even earlier, she **had arrived**. All of these events occurred **before** the past reference time, and consequently are cast in the past perfect.